# Is it possible to do start iterating from an element other than the first using foreach?

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable

I'm thinking about implementing IEnumerable for my custom collection (a tree) so I can use foreach to traverse my tree. However as far as I know foreach always starts from the first element of the collection.  I would like to choose from which element foreach starts.  Is it possible to somehow change the element from which foreach starts?

Comment: I would follow the principle of least astonishment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: If you don't start from the first element, how do you define the iterator's behavior? What happens when it reaches the end of the sequence? Does it then go back to the first element and iterate over the remaining elements?

Comment: @ChaosPandion's comment is where I was going with those questions. :)

Answer (score 200):

Yes. Do the following:

```
Collection<string> myCollection = new Collection<string>;

foreach (string curString in myCollection.Skip(3))
    //Dostuff
```

`Skip` is an IEnumerable function that skips however many you specify starting at the current index. On the other hand, if you wanted to use *only* the first three you would use `.Take`:

```
foreach (string curString in myCollection.Take(3))
```

These can even be paired together, so if you only wanted the 4-6 items you could do:

```
foreach (string curString in myCollection.Skip(3).Take(3))
```

Comment: Good call. WTB auto-complete (gahh can't remember the real name of it) in stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Does this actually skip or does it just create a copy? I.E. would these two be different:
`foreach(List<string> row in rows.skip(1)){
      row[0] = "newInfo";
}`

vs 
`for(int i=1; i<rows.Count;i++){
     List<string> row = rows[i];
     row[0] = "newStuff";
}`

Answer (score 29):

It's easiest to use the [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) method in LINQ to Objects for this, to skip a given number of elements:

```
foreach (var value in sequence.Skip(1)) // Skips just one value
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously just change 1 for any other value to skip a different number of elements...

Similarly you can use [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to limit the number of elements which are returned.

You can read more about both of these (and the related `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` methods) in [my Edulinq blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-23-take-skip-takewhile-skipwhile.aspx).

Comment: Jon, doesn't this run the risk of an exception if "sequence" is Null?

Comment: @WEFX: Well we have no idea whether `sequence` can legitimately be `null` or not. Presumably the OP can handle that themselves - it's not really part of the question...

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Enumerable.Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) to skip some elements, and have it start there.

For example:

```
foreach(item in theTree.Skip(9))  // Skips the first 9 items
{
    // Do something
```

However, if you're writing a tree, you might want to provide a member on the tree item itself that will return a new `IEnumerable<T>` which will enumerate from there down.  This would, potentially, be more useful in the long run.

Comment: Something like `IEnumerable<T> SubTree(rootIndex)`? Good call!

Comment: Thanks for answer, skip looks promising , reading MSDN information about skip I got to conclusion that maybe it is possible to write a  method  StartFrom(this IEnumerable<MyTree> tree, MyTreeElement element) which would be an extension method for IEnumerable<MyTree> which would return IEnumerable<MyTreeElement> from which I should start iterating. Then maybe I could use this method as foreach(var element in tree.StartFrom(someElement))).

Comment: @inferno: Yes, you could easily do that.  However, I would just add a method/property to MyTreeElement that was more like: `IEnumerable<MyTreeElement> Children`, so you could just do:  `foreach(var item in someElement.Children)` - much more clear than using extension methods IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip reading Rows in a `DataGridView`, try this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow().Skip(3))
```

If you want to copy contents of one `DataGridView` to another skipping rows, try this,

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Skip(3))
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        string value = cell.Value.ToString();
        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = cell.Value.ToString();
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    j = 0;
}
```

this copies the contents from one `DataGridView` to another skipping 3 rows.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked - the question doesn't mention `DataGridView` at all (or even a UI framework).

Comment: @NightOwl888 this was answered because the question was about skipping some iterations and iterating after that in foreach loop. In my example i just used Skip() to apply on DataGridView.

Answer (score -1):

`Foreach` will iterate over your collection in the way defined by your implementation of `IEnumerable`. So, although you can skip elements (as suggested above), you're still technically iterating over the elements in the same order.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your class could have multiple `IEnumerable` properties, each of which enumerates the elements in a specific order.